# Scrapy with Selenium Middleware to generate second response after first response

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests, scrapy

I'm trying to extract comments from a news page. The Crawler starts at the homepage and follows all the internal links found on the site. The comments are just on the article-sites and those comments are embedded from an external Website, so the section with the comments are in an JavaScript iframe. [Here's an example article site](https://www.merkur.de/welt/novavax-corona-totimpfstoff-omikron-variante-lauterbach-zulassung-impfstoff-weihnachten-wirkung-zr-91197497.html#id-Comments)

My first Step was to build a crawler and a selenium middleware. The crawler follows all the links and those are loaded through Selenium:

```
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class CrawlerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'crawler'
    allowed_domains = ['www.merkur.de', 'disqus.com/embed/comments/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.merkur.de/welt/novavax-corona-totimpfstoff-omikron-zulassung-impfstoff-weihnachten-wirkung-covid-lauterbach-zr-91197497.html']
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'.*'), callback='parse',
    follow=True)]

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.xpath('//html/head/title/text()').extract_first()
        iframe_url = response.xpath('//iframe[@title="Disqus"]//@src').get()
        yield Request(iframe_url, callback=self.next_parse, meta={'title': title})


    def next_parse(self, response):
        title = response.meta.get('title')
        comments = response.xpath("//div[@class='post-message ']/div/p").getall()
        yield {
            'title': title,
            'comments': comments
        }
```

To get access to the iframe elements the Scrapy Request goes through the middleware:

```
from scrapy import signals, spiders
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

class SeleniumMiddleware(object):  
    def __init__(self):
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

    # Here you get the request you are making to the urls with the LinkExtractor found and use selenium to get them and return a response.
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        self.driver.get(request.url)
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="disqus_thread"]')
        self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
        time.sleep(1)
        body = self.driver.page_source
        return HtmlResponse(self.driver.current_url, body=body, encoding='utf-8', request=request)
```

I am getting the right link from the iframe src [here](https://disqus.com/embed/comments/?base=default&f=id-merkur-online&t_i=91197497&t_u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.merkur.de%2Fwelt%2Fnovavax-corona-totimpfstoff-omikron-variante-lauterbach-zulassung-impfstoff-weihnachten-wirkung-zr-91197497.html&t_d=Novavax-Hammer%20zum%20Fest%3A%20Vakzin%20bietet%20Schutz%20vor%20Omikron-Variante%20-%20WHO-Empfehlung%20f%C3%BCr%20einige%20Gruppen&t_t=Novavax-Hammer%20zum%20Fest%3A%20Vakzin%20bietet%20Schutz%20vor%20Omikron-Variante%20-%20WHO-Empfehlung%20f%C3%BCr%20einige%20Gruppen&s_o=default#version=bf0dae6ac2c9986f44bf1da0d7c5c414) but my CrawlerSpider is not yielding the iframe_url Request so that I can follow the link from the iframe. What am I doing wrong here ? I really appreciate your help!